# Make not picking the needed target

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have written a make file for a program as under

```
Panther!simpleguy:~/Code [62]$ cat make.def

CC = gcc
LIBS = -lpthread
CODE_FILE = Code_In_C.c
EXECUTABLE = Code_In_C

all : ${CODE_FILE}
        ${CC} -o ${EXECUTABLE} ${LIBS} ${CODE_FILE}
```

I tried to make it using below command

```
Panther!simpleguy:~/Code [63]$ make all make.def
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

**Why is it not picking 'all' which is defined in make file (make.def) ?**

Comment: did you try `make -f make.def all`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [online GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names),

> Normally you should call your makefile either `makefile` or `Makefile`.

and

> If you want to use a nonstandard name for your makefile, you can specify the makefile name with the `-f` or `--file` option. The arguments `-f name` or `--file=name` tell make to read the file `name` as the makefile.

So, you should use the following syntax to specify a makefile with *nonstandard name*

```
make -f make.def all
```